# objdump - head ELF - Meaning of flags?

Tags: objdump

$ objdump -f ./a.out

```
./a.out:     file format elf32-i386
architecture: i386, flags 0x00000112:
EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS, D_PAGED
start address 0x080484e0
```

$ objdump -f function.o

```
function.o:     file format elf32-i386
architecture: i386, flags 0x00000011:
HAS_RELOC, HAS_SYMS
start address 0x00000000
```

What is the meaning of flags 0x00000011 and 0x00000112? Nothing in the ELF header file has this flag.

Does someone have an idea about their meaning?

Comment: are you trying to figure out what flags such as EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS, etc. mean?  your question is not clear to me.

Comment: The meaning of flags 0x00000112: or flags 0x00000011:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are BFD-specific bitmasks. In the binutils source tree, see bfd/bfd-in2.h:

```
  /* BFD contains relocation entries.  */
#define HAS_RELOC      0x01

  /* BFD is directly executable.  */
#define EXEC_P         0x02
...
  /* BFD has symbols.  */
#define HAS_SYMS       0x10
...
  /* BFD is dynamically paged (this is like an a.out ZMAGIC file) (the
     linker sets this by default, but clears it for -r or -n or -N).  */
#define D_PAGED        0x100
```

These flag values won't appear in your object file; they are simply an in-memory representation that libbfd uses.

Answer (score -1):

They are LibBFD flags.
You're trying to recode objdump ? ... =)