# Why Linux/gnu linker chose address 0x400000?

Tags: linux, x86, x86-64, ld, elf

I'm experimenting with ELF executables and the gnu toolchain on Linux x86_64:

I've linked and stripped (by hand) a "Hello World" test.s:

```
        .global _start
        .text
_start:
        mov     $1, %rax
        ...
```

into a 267 byte ELF64 executable...

```
0000000: 7f45 4c46 0201 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000  .ELF............
0000010: 0200 3e00 0100 0000 d400 4000 0000 0000  ..>.......@.....
0000020: 4000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  @...............
0000030: 0000 0000 4000 3800 0100 4000 0000 0000  ....@.8...@.....
0000040: 0100 0000 0500 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000050: 0000 4000 0000 0000 0000 4000 0000 0000  ..@.......@.....
0000060: 0b01 0000 0000 0000 0b01 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000070: 0000 2000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  .. .............
0000080: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000090: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000b0: 0400 0000 1400 0000 0300 0000 474e 5500  ............GNU.
00000c0: c3b0 cbbd 0abf a73c 26ef e960 fc64 4026  .......<&..`.d@&
00000d0: e242 8bc7 48c7 c001 0000 0048 c7c7 0100  .B..H......H....
00000e0: 0000 48c7 c6fe 0040 0048 c7c2 0d00 0000  ..H....@.H......
00000f0: 0f05 48c7 c03c 0000 0048 31ff 0f05 4865  ..H..<...H1...He
0000100: 6c6c 6f2c 2057 6f72 6c64 0a              llo, World.
```

It has one program header (LOAD) and no sections:

```
There are 1 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x000000000000010b 0x000000000000010b  R E    200000
```

This seems to load the entire file (file offset 0 thru 0x10b - elf header and all) at address 0x400000.

The entry point is:

```
 Entry point address:               0x4000d4
```

Which corresponds to 0xd4 offset in the file, and as we can see that address is the start of the machine code (`mov $1, %rax1`)

My question is why (how) did the gnu linker choose address `0x400000` to map the file to?

Comment: 1 megabyte seems like a nice round number to me, what would you choose?

Comment: `ld` is driven by scripts. The default script mentions that `0x400000`, IIRC.... Otherwise download it and look inside `binutils` source code.

Comment: @CarlNorum: Are you implying that 0x400000 is 1 megabyte?  Try 4 megabytes. 1 meg = 20 bits = 5 x 4 bit hex digits = 0x100000

Comment: Whoops - good catch.  Sorry about that!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488010/why-the-entry-point-address-in-my-executable-is-0x8048330-0x330-being-offset-of

Comment: Windows uses the same default base address, here's why Windows chose it: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141003-00/?p=43923

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The start address is usually set by a linker script.

For example, on GNU/Linux, looking at `/usr/lib/ldscripts/elf_x86_64.x` we see:

```
...
PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000)); \
    . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
```

The value `0x400000` is the default value for the `SEGMENT_START()` function on this platform.

You can find out more about linker scripts by browsing the linker manual:

```
% info ld Scripts
```

Comment: Yeah, but why 0x400000 in particular, and not some other value?

Comment: Better yet, use `ld --verbose`.

Answer (score 10):

`ld`'s default linker script has that `0x400000` value baked in for non-PIE executables.

PIEs (Position Independent Executables) don't have default base address; they're always relocated by the kernel, with the *kernel's* default being `0x0000555...` plus some ASLR offset unless ASLR is disabled for this process or system-wide.  `ld` has no control over this.  Note that most modern systems configure GCC to use `-fPIE -pie` by default, so it passes `-pie` to `ld`, and turns C into asm that's position-independent.  Hand-written asm [has to follow the same rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux) if you link it that way.

### But what makes `0x400000` (4 MiB) a good default?

#### **It has to be above [`mmap_min_addr`](https://wiki.debian.org/mmap_min_addr)** = 65536 = 64K by default.

And being plenty far away from 0 gives plenty more room to guard against NULL deref with an offset reading `.text` or `.data`/`.bss` memory (`array[i]` where `array` is NULL). Even without increasing `mmap_min_addr` (which this leave room for without breaking executables), usually `mmap` randomly picks high addresses so in practice we have at least 4MiB of guard against NULL deref.

#### 2M-aligned is good

This puts it at the start of a page-directory in the next level up of [the page tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46509152/why-in-x86-64-the-virtual-address-are-4-bits-shorter-than-physical-48-bits-vs/46510887#46510887) means the same number of 4K page-table-entries will be split across fewer 2M page directory entries, saving kernel page-table memory and helping page-walk hardware cache better.  For big static arrays, close to the start of a 1G subtree of the next level up is also good.

IDK why 4MiB instead of 2MiB, or what the developers' reasoning was.  [4MiB is the 32-bit largepage size without PAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension#Page_table_structures) (4-byte PTEs so 10 bits per level instead of 9), but a CPU has to be using x86-64 page tables to be in 64-bit mode.

#### A low start address allows nearly 2 GiB of static arrays

(Without using a larger code model, where at least large arrays have to be addressed in ways that are sometimes less efficient.  See section 3.5.1 Architectural Constraints in the [x86-64 System V ABI document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133812/where-is-the-x86-64-system-v-abi-documented) for details on code models.)

The default code model for non-PIE executables ("small") lets programs assume that any static address is in the low 2GiB of virtual address space. So any absolute address in `.text`/`.rodata`, `.data`, `.bss` can be used as a 32-bit sign-extended immediate in the machine code where that's more efficient.

(This is not the case in a PIE or shared library: see  *[32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux)* for the things you / the compiler can't do in x86-64 asm as a result, notably `addss xmm0, [foo + rdi*4]` instead requires a RIP-relative LEA to get the array start address into a register.  x86-64's only RIP-relative addressing mode is [RIP+rel32], without any general-purpose registers.)

**Starting the executable's [sections/segments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361248/whats-the-difference-of-section-and-segment-in-elf-file-format) near the bottom of virtual address space leaves almost the whole 2GiB available for text+data+bss to be that big.**  (It might have been possible to have a higher default, and have large executables make ld choose a lower address to make them fit, but that would be a more complicated linker script.)

This includes zero-initialized arrays in the .bss which don't make the *executable file* huge, just the process image in memory.  In practice, Fortran programmers tend to run into this more than C and C++, since static arrays are popular there. For example *[gfortran for dummies: What does mcmodel=medium do exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916176/gfortran-for-dummies-what-does-mcmodel-medium-do-exactly)* has a good explanation of a build error with the default `small` model, and the resulting x86-64 asm difference for `medium` (where objects above a certain size threshold are not assumed to be in the low 2G or within +-2G of the code.  But code and smaller static data still is so the speed penalty is minor.)

For example `static float arr[1UL<<28];` is a 1 GiB array.  If you had 3 of them, they couldn't all *start* inside the low 2 GiB (which may be all you need for hand-written asm), let alone have each element accessible.

`gcc -fno-pie` expects to be able to compile `float *p = &arr[size-1];` to `mov $arr+1073741820, %edi`, a 5-byte `mov $imm32`.  RIP-relative won't work either if the target address is more than 2GiB away from the code generating the address (or loading from it with `movss arr+1073741820(%rip), %xmm0`; [RIP-relative is the normal way to load/store static data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967075/why-does-this-movss-instruction-use-rip-relative-addressing) even in a non-PIE, when there's no runtime-variable index.) That's why the small-PIC model also has a 2GiB size limit on text+data+bss (plus gaps between segments): all static data and code needs to be within 2GiB of any other that might want to reach it.

If your code only ever accesses high elements or their addresses via runtime-variable indices, you only need the start of each array, the symbol itself, to be in the low 2 GiB.  I forget if the linker enforces having the end-of-bss within the low 2GiB; it might since the linker script puts a symbol there that some CRT startup code might reference.

---

**Footnote 1**: There aren't any useful smaller sizes for a code model smaller than 2GiB.  x86-64 machine code uses either 8 or 32-bit for immediates and addressing mode.  8-bit (256 bytes) is too small to be usable, and many important instructions like `call rel32`, `mov r32, imm32`, and `[rip+rel32]` addressing, are only available with 4-byte not 1-byte constants anyway.

Limiting to the low 2 GiB (instead of 4) means that addresses can safely be zero-extended as with `mov edi, OFFSET arr`, or sign-extended, as with `mov eax, [arr + rdi*4]`.  Remember that addresses aren't the only use-case for `[reg + disp32]` addressing modes; `[rbp - 256]` can often make sense, so it's good that x86-64 machine code sign-extends disp8 and disp32 to 64-bit, not zero-extends.

Implicit zero-extension to 64-bit happens when writing a 32-bit register, as with `mov`-immediate to put an address in a register, where 32-bit operand-size is a smaller machine-code instruction than 64-bit operand-size.  See [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212012/how-to-load-address-of-function-or-label-into-register) (which also covers RIP-relative LEA).

---

### Related for 32-bit Windows

[Raymond Chen wrote an article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141003-00/?p=43923) about why the same `0x400000` base address is the default *for 32-bit Windows*.

He mentions that DLLs get loaded at high addresses by default, and a low address is far from that.  x86-64 SysV shared objects can get loaded anywhere there's a large enough gap of address space, with the kernel defaulting to near the top of user-space virtual address-space, i.e. the top of the canonical range.  But ELF shared objects are required to be fully relocatable so would work fine anywhere.

The 4MiB choice for 32-bit Windows was also motivated by avoiding the low 64K (NULL deref), and by picking the start of a page-directory for legacy 32-bit page tables.  (Where the "largepage" size is 4M, not 2M for x86-64 or PAE.)  With a bunch of Win95 and Win3.1 legacy memory-map reasons why at least 1MiB or 4MiB was partially necessary, and stuff like working around CPU bugs.

Comment: Apparently I already wrote this answer a year earlier on a different question, [Why is address 0x400000 chosen as a start of text segment in x86\_64 ABI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67679629) , but forgot about it.

Answer (score 2):

Page zero of task's virtual address space is kept unmapped so that null-pointer references could be catched through page-fault exception leading to SIGSEGV. 4 MB fit with "big page" granularity (as opposed to "normal page" granularity 4 KB) - so on settings with 4 MB page granularity, 0x000000 to 0x3FFFFF address range is unmapped, making 0x400000 the first valid address in task's virtual address space.

Comment: The default for `/proc/sys/vm/mmap_min_addr` is 64kiB on x86-64 Linux, so you can map stuff at lower addresses if you want.  (See  https://wiki.debian.org/mmap_min_addr).  Some of this idea makes some sense, though: 0x400000 is hugepage-aligned which can be good for transparent-hugepages.  (But note that x86-64 hugepages are 2MiB and 1GiB; only the legacy 32-bit page-tables have 4M hugepages.  And `ld` has a different default base address for i386: `0x08048000`, somewhat above 128.28 MiB)

Comment: Choosing an address that's 2M aligned and near the start of a 1G region means a better chance of denser page tables, i.e. same number of PTEs split between fewer page directories.  The memory in the low 4MiB is unlikely to get randomly mapped, though, so usually you do have that full 4MiB buffer against null-deref.

Comment: AFAIK, i386 code base 0x8000000 was used so that stack section could be placed below this base address. This leads to implicit guard mechanisms - TOS overflow into unmapped zeroth page throws an exception, as well as TOS underflow into code section which is read-only by default, thus throwing an exception, too. And 128 MB was chosen to provide enough room for stack section. To be honest, I'm in doubt about plausibility of that approach as the same effect could be achieved no matter where in virtual address space by surrounding the stack region with unmapped pages.

Comment: That's not where current Linux puts the user-space stack.  Are you suggesting the original design was totally different, and didn't respect `ulimit -s` for the stack growth limit?  The current mechanism actually grows the *mapping* (for the initial / main-thread stack), not just soft page-faulting in new physical pages for an existing logical mapping.  (You can see that in `/proc/<PID>/maps`, and that it won't grow if ESP / RSP isn't below the address accessed.  See [How is Stack memory allocated when using 'push' or 'sub' x86 instructions?](//stackoverflow.com/q/46790666) for some details)

Comment: (Current Linux puts the user-space stack at or near the top of user-space virtual address space.  Under a 64-bit kernel, 32-bit processes get a stack address like `0xffff....` or something like that, else `0x7ffff000` or so.

Comment: I know it works the way you mentioned. I just wrote what I had learned from someone else. Who knows whether there originally was some intent to do stuff that way or there was some different reason why to reserve some space at the beginning of virtual address space.