# How to add symbols to gdb after code relocation?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, u-boot

I was step tracing uboot execution right from power on. During initial boot, uboot relocates itself. In my case the relocated address (`relocaddr`) is 0x3bf53000. So I did the following and was able to do step debugging even after relocation :

```
>>> p /x ((struct global_data)*0x3bb4eda0)->relocaddr
$1 = 0x3bf53000
>>> add-symbol-file u-boot 0x3bf53000
add symbol table from file "u-boot" at
    .text_addr = 0x3bf53000
(y or n) y
Reading symbols from u-boot...
>>> b board_init_r
Breakpoint 4 at 0x9ab54: board_init_r. (2 locations)
>>> info b
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       breakpoint     keep n   0x00000000000825f8 <relocate_code+20>
    breakpoint already hit 1 time
2       breakpoint     keep y   <MULTIPLE>
2.1                         y   0x000000000009ab58 <board_init_r+4>
2.2                         y   0x000000003bf6db54 in board_init_r at common/board_r.c:797
```

All good so far.
When I look at the binary, the symbols is located at the following offset.

```
naveen@workstation:~/.repos/src/arm64/u-boot$ readelf -s u-boot | grep board_init_r
  5162: 000000000009ab54   132 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 board_init_r
```

So why can't I simply put a breakpoint at address `0x3bf53000 (relocaddr) + 0x9ab54 (offset) = 0x3BFEDB54` ? Instead when used gdb command `add-symbol-file u-boot 0x3bf53000`, it set breakpoint at `0x3bf6db54`. Why a difference of `0x80000`? Now this is a special value because if I am not wrong, this is also the load address where u-boot is originally loaded. So this is indicating that `0x9ab54` is an absolute load address and I should be subtracting `0x80000` from it and add that difference to the `relocaddr` to get the new breakpoint address. Is my understanding correct? If yes, can someone please help with some readelf or similar commands that I can use to confirm this logic?

I tried it but not sure why there are 4 entries for same address. I was expecting just `_start`.

```
naveen@workstation:~/.repos/src/arm64/u-boot$ readelf -s u-boot  | grep 0000000000080000
     1: 0000000000080000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1
    26: 0000000000080000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $x
  5419: 0000000000080000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _start
  6138: 0000000000080000     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 __image_copy_start
```

Comment: Found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296276/base-address-of-elf and this supports my observation.