# Some questions about ELF file format

Tags: elf, arm64

I am trying to learn how ELF files are structured and probably how to make one manually.

I am working on aarch64 Linux OS, the ELF files I am inspecting are of `elf64-littleaarch64` format.

Also I try to learn by myself, however I got stuck with some questions...

1. When I do `xxd code`, the first number in each line of the output specifies the address of bytes in the file. But when `objdump -D code`, the first number is something like `4000b0`, however corresponds to `000000b0` in `xxd`. Why is there a four at the beginning?
2. In `objdump`, the bytecode is for example `11000a94`, which 'means'
   `add w20, w20, #2` in assembly. I know, that `11` is the opcode, but what does `000a94` mean? I thought, it should be the parameters, but I am adding the value 2 and can't find the number 2 in it.

If you have a good article to read, or can help me explain this, I will be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `xxd` shows the offset of the bytes within the file on disk.  `objdump -D` shows (tentatively) the address in memory where those bytes will be loaded when the program is run.  It is common for them to differ by a round number.  In particular, `0x400000` may correspond to one higher-level page table entry; see [Why Linux/gnu linker chose address 0x400000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314021/why-linux-gnu-linker-chose-address-0x400000) which is for x86-64 but I think ARM64 is similar (haven't checked).  It doesn't have anything to do with the fact that `0x40` is ASCII `@`; that's just a coincidence.

   Note that if [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) is in use, the actual memory address will be randomly chosen every time the program is run, and will not match what `objdump` shows you, though the difference will still be a multiple of the page size.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was too fast asking this question, but now, I will answer it too.

1. `40` at the beginning of the addresses in `objdump` is the hex representation of the char "@", which means "at" and points to an address, very simple!
2. Little Endian has CPU addresses stored in 5 bits instead of 6 or 8. That means, that I should look for the binary value of the `objdump` code: `11000a94` --> `10001000000000000101010010100`, where it can be divided into `[10001][00000000000010][10100][10100]` with `[opcode][value][first address][second address]`

Both answers are wrong, see the accepted answer.
I will still let them here, though

Comment: For #2, these 5-bit numbers are *register* numbers. You wouldn't normally call them "CPU addresses" because that is too easy to confuse with *memory* addresses, which these are not.  It also has nothing to do with big or little endian. Full details about ARM64 instruction encoding is in the ARMv8 Architecture Reference Manual, C4.1.

Comment: Yup, since I am not learning from somewhere, but myself, I don't really know, how to call things right, thank you for your answer