# Page-Structure Cache perf events

Tags: assembly, x86, perf, tlb, page-tables

I've been always thinking that if linear address translation process encounters TLB miss then it traverses page directory structure in memory. However Intel Manual Vol.3/4.10.3 defines the so called **Paging-Structure Caches** which I've not heard about before.

This is what it's done for TLB miss:

> If the processor does not find a relevant TLB entry or PDE-cache
> entry, it may use the upper bits of the linear address (for 4-level
> paging, bits 47:30; for 5-level paging, bits 56:30) to select an entry
> from the PDPTE cache that is associated with the current PCID. It can
> then use that entry to complete the translation process (locating a
> PDE, etc.) as if it had traversed the PDPTE, the PML4E, and (for
> 5-level paging) the PML5E corresponding to the PDPTE-cache entry

and

> If the processor does not find a relevant TLB entry, PDE-cache entry,
> or PDPTE-cache entry, it may use the upper bits of the linear address
> (for 4-level paging, bits 47:39; for 5-level paging, bits 56:39) to
> select an entry from the PML4E cache that is associated with the
> current PCID. It can then use that entry to complete the translation
> process (locating a PDPTE, etc.) as if it had traversed the
> corresponding PML4E.

So TLB miss does not necessarily means traversing the **whole** page structure.

Could you give some examples of perf events describing the Page-Structure Caches access and how to optimize for Page-Structure Cache usage?

Comment: My recollection is that neither AMD nor Intel have provided any significant details about the implementation of their page-structure caches.  Even if one reverse-engineers implementation details for one processor model, the implied optimizations for page-structure cache usage may not apply to other models.  The good news is that the existing implementations handle page table accesses extremely efficiently (especially if large pages are used).  On a Xeon Platinum 8380 (Ice Lake Xeon), random accesses in tables up to ~160 GiB will find most of their PTEs in the L2 cache (using 2MiB pages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Skylake doesn't have any perf events for the details of page walks.  There are counters for number of walks completed, and number of cycles with walks active, so I guess you could try to average how long each walk took.

(There are two PMH page-miss handlers in Skylake and later, but `dtlb_load_misses.walk_pending` counts 1 or 2 per cycle depending on how many are active.  Or 0 for neither.  But it might only be counting for demand-load TLB misses, not next-page TLB prefetch. There are similar events for stores and code-fetch.
Some other events like `dtlb_load_misses.walk_active` counts cycles when one or both page-walkers are active.)

---

The main way to take advantage of the page walkers caching higher levels of the page table (and/or L2 / L1d also caching those physical locations) **is to have locality on a larger scale**, like have the hot pages in your working set within the same aligned 2M or 1G regions, so they all share a common upper part of the radix tree (page tables).

Or within a few groups; you don't need to try to get `malloc` / `mmap` to allocate next to your code or the stack.

That's mostly up to your OS, unless you do one big allocation and carve it up yourself.

Static code/data (at least in a non-PIE Linux executable) [starts at absolute address 4MiB by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314021/why-linux-gnu-linker-chose-address-0x400000), which is at the start of a 2M largepage, and near the start of a 1G hugepage.  And very near the start of the 2^9 G level above that.  So even if you have a *lot* of code + data, it's well-positioned.  I assume ASLR for non-PIE executables is more granular, but static code+data is usually pretty small compared to even a 1G level.