# How to recover the flags: EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS, D_PAGED

Tags: c, object-files

I am coding the function objdump and I would like to know how to recover the flags (HAS_SYMS, D_PAGED) with their addresses.

where is the HAS_SYMS,D_PAGED flags in the elf.h structure ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235844/objdump-head-elf-meaning-of-flags

Comment: where are the HAS_SYMS,D_PAGED flags in the elf.h structure ? without the BFD lib.

Comment: Quoting from cited answer "These flag values won't appear in your object file; they are simply an in-memory representation that libbfd uses." where they are? in `/usr/include/bfd.h` in `struct bfd{.../* Format_specific flags.  */ flagword flags;...};`. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74601/portions-of-the-file-header and https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.23.1/bfd/BFD-front-end.html#BFD-front-end.